# Visual Studio or Resharper extension to decompile code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Does anyone know of a Visual Studio extension that will decompile assemblies and allows you to view code in Visual Studio for a given class instead of having to leave VS and use ILSpy or other "external" reflection tools? I Know Resharper also has a reflection tool but it would be nice if you could kick it off within VS.

Comment: I think Reflector does that: http://www.reflector.net/category/visual-studio/

Comment: example of question: right click class and "browse to definition" of compiled class and see decompiled code instead of skeleton class.

Comment: Nice that's exactly what I am looking to do. Now if only it was free again.

Comment: What do you mean by 'kick it off within vs'? With ReSharper you can navigate to decompiled sources right in Visual Studio.

Comment: What's wrong with the dotPeek functionality built into Resharper?

Comment: It wasn't working for me but then I realized I had to set a setting in external sources. With that set I'm getting exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I Know Resharper also has a reflection tool but it would be nice if you could kick it off within VS.

You can. With the cursor on an identifier, choose `ReSharper | Navigate | Navigate To...` (the keyboard shortcut in the VS scheme is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>), and choose `Decompiled Sources`.

This uses the same decompilation engine as dotPeek, the standalone tool.

Note that within such a decompiled source, you must continue to use this same navigation method to follow definitions, as <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click will go back to the Object Browser.

Comment: If you do not have such command, make sure that anything except "Default Visual Studio Navigation" item is selected in the Tools/External Sources options page in ReSharper (as described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Decompiled_Code.html ).

Answer (score 34):

Newer versions of Visual Studio 2017 now include an experimental feature called [navigation to decompiled sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c). It requires you to explicitly enable it (and restart Visual Studio), but once you do, you can see decompiled source code for assemblies your code references.

For instance, if you put your caret (text cursor) over the name of a method in a method call and press <kbd>F12</kbd> (by default) it will open a new tab right in the IDE that shows the decompiled source code for that method. Microsoft says this uses ILSpy behind the scenes, but this is a lot more convenient and doesn't require you installing anything new.

Comment: How does this compare to DotPeek etc? I had a brief look and it seemed very similar. I wonder if it gives better results in some cases. Edit: Seems it uses ILSpy like everything else.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. R# had this going for it for a good number of years, but now VS finally offers a perfectly workable alternative out of the box.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming the default short-cut keys where pressing F12 while a class/method is in-focus, you can set ReSharper to automatically decompile the reference. This ends up working great and it's as if the external assembly reference was like any other class in your source solution.

[image]

Example of source you are directed to when pressing F12 while focused on `new HttpClient()`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) which has a built-in VS integration for assemblies decompilation and is far, far better than Resharper. Have a look at [this page](http://www.reflector.net/category/visual-studio/) for further knowledge.

Comment: It was free, but now unfortunately a una tantum payment is required to obtain a valid license. Anyway, if you decompile assemblies often, it's an absolutely invaluable tool and it's worth it's price.

Comment: right I'd up vote your response but unfortunately S.O. won't let me till I get more points. So thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can you detail how it is better than resharper? Is this still correct in 2018?

Answer (score 4):

http://ilspy.net/ is free and Open Source. And has a plugin for Visual Studio.